# Javascript function return as object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, properties

I'm trying to return the value of a function as an object property (as opposed to the function itself). This is my code right now, but it breaks when I try to access option_list[0][0].label or .value within my jQuery plugin. Thoughts?

```
$('#new').create({
    option_list:function(){return [
        [
            {label:'option1', value:'1'},
            {label:'option2', value:'2'},
            {label:'option3', value:'3'}
        ]
    ];}
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to actually invoke the function, like so ...

```
$('#new').create({
    option_list:(function(){return [
        [
            {label:'option1', value:'1'},
            {label:'option2', value:'2'},
            {label:'option3', value:'3'}
        ]
    ];}())
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I get you wrong but why do you want to have such a multidimensional array?

Let the function give you an object with an encapsulated array:

```
$('#new').create({
    option_list:function(){ return {
        [
            {label:'option1', value:'1'},
            {label:'option2', value:'2'},
            {label:'option3', value:'3'}
        ]
    };}
});
```

Comment: without full context, it seems superfluous, but it's part of a bigger form-generation schema. is there a reason returning and object vs. an array would be better?